# Web config transforms not working with Visual Studio online, VS2013 and Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, web.config-transform

I have an MVC5 website successfully deploying a staging and production release to Azure using continuous integration from Visual Studio Online (TFS).

I have followed this blog post
[Continuous Delivery to Azure Websites with git using custom deployment script](http://chriskirby.net/continuous-delivery-to-azure-websites-with-git-using-custom-deployment-script/)

I have even added the build that is required to build to my publish profiles. ie.
`stagingbuild | any cpu`.

> **note**: this was not mentioned in the above mentioned blog post.

The sites deploy ok using by VS2013 build but the configs are not transformed. I just get the default `web.config` settings and not the transformed ones from `web.staging.config` etc.

> **note**: I am only trying to transform one `appSetting` at the moment to get it working

I totally understand how to write transforms so I don't think this is an issue and when I preview my transforms in VS2013 they transform in the previewer window.

> **note**: I am not publishing directly from VS but committing my changes to repo and continuous integration kicks in from my Visual Studio Online repo.

Comment: Just a check.if you publish to a local folder does the transformation work ? though web config transformations are offered out of the box ,You can also try using slowcheetah. https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/

Comment: Thanks I will try that but in the end.. publishing is different to continuous integration. Yeah, I used to use slow cheetah but I though VS 2013 replaced the need for slow cheetah?

Comment: Yes Publishing is one piece of it. VS 2013 takes care of that for web.config files and not for the app config in worker roles.(it is not applicable in your case though). I wanted you to check locally to confirm that it works fine there and does not work in CI alone.

Comment: Aravind.  I'll try that today. End for your help

Comment: Aravind, I set up a new local publish profile that builds out to a folder that IIS points to. It also takes care of my local. I can confirm that the config transforms. Any ideas about my CI builds?

Comment: It should be working the same way in CI also. check for any errors in the log.

Comment: @RuSs: Did you happen to resolve this issue related to config transforms and Azure CI?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Open **Builds** in **Team Explorer**
- **Edit Build Definition** of your build
- Set Process > Build > Configurations > **Any CPU|Release** or any other configuration/CPU combo.

[image]

Comment: This is not working for me. The web.config is not transformed.