# Trying to replace connectionStrings element for continous deployment in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: c#, .net, azure, web-config, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Team Services, previously Visual Studio Online, to continuously deploy my web app. I have tried setting up the web.config transformation, I believe it is working after I have changed the configurations setting to Release | Any CPU as instructed here [Web config transforms not working with Visual Studio online, VS2013 and Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500203/web-config-transforms-not-working-with-visual-studio-online-vs2013-and-azure) .

The issue I believe I am having is more with the transform its self.

Right now I have the following in my web.config

`<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>`

I want this so I can avoid checking in `connections.config` and still have my db connections setup locally. What I want to do is replace the above line of code with something like this.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="umbracoDB" connectionString="blah " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="EFdb" connectionString="blah" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am using

`<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(configSource)"/>` 
and it seems to be successfully removing the configSource connectionStrings element. But I am still confused on how to add back my replacement connectionStrings and add elements?

Devin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace your connectionStrings element during deployment, try usign the Replace transform:

```
<connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <add name="umbracoDB" connectionString="blah " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="EFdb" connectionString="blah" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly, now I am able to use my Azure connection strings to override and can keep my connection strings out of source control. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you can do is to store your DB connection strings as secret variables in Build/Release and then use the [Tokenizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks) task from Marketplace
to replace the connection string token with actual string.

Tokenizer task has support for the environments in Release Management.

Comment: Why not just use the functionality built into Azure for connection strings?

Comment: Definitely, if you can make use of that. I was/am not aware of that, so mentioned a generic solution which will work even if isn't Azure.